# What does it mean when it's said it's a "16 bit key" or "64/128 bit key"

Tags: encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I need some detailed explanation on the length of the key? What it means when someone says  it's a 16 bit key or 128 bit key etc. The [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size) definition is "*In cryptography, key size, key length, or key space refer to the number of bits in a key used by a cryptographic algorithm*"

Referring to the statement from Wiki, the next question is: How to determine number of bits in a key?

I'm getting confused as there is no example specified, could anyone advise with simple examples?

Comment: You need to take a basic cryptography course. Consider Stanford's free online [Cryptography 1](https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key is a sequence of bits. The length is the number of bits in the key. A simple example of a 16-bit key would be 1010 1010 1010 1010 (0x5555 or decimal 21,845). Any sixteen-bit number. A 128-bit key would be any 128-bit number.

Comment: @Aniruddha I honestly wonder why that is more understandable than the Wikpedia statement? "The key length [or] key size refer to the number of bits in a key" vs. "The length is the number of bits in the key"? Did it help to see the example of bits in a row?

Comment: Sometimes a concept is so simple, that it's easy for learners to believe it can't possibly be *that* simple. In my teaching experience, seeing the same concept expressed many ways is often helpful. I appreciate cryptography specs that include careful examples of things as trivial as `X|Y` concatenation. I'm happy when people are not afraid to ask basic questions; it makes me braver to ask questions I feel might make me look foolish.

Comment: @not2savvy In my opinion examples are necessary, and indeed a simple example from Rob made me understand what exactly a key length is? In most of the article out on internet nobody bothers to specify the example which keeps things unclear for people like me. A simple Google search of 'What is a 64-bit key?' will take you to depths of encryption and it doesn't make any sense without knowing the basics of it.

Comment: @RobNapier Many thanks for your kind consideration and helping me understand the very basic.

Comment: @Aniruddha Makes sense! Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me. It  helps me in writing my own documentation.